# How to check if my Qualcomm gimbal beacon is working or not?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ibeacon, gimbal

I have currently bought a **Qualcomm Gimbal Beacon** device. But when I added my device at Gimbal's developer site it shows that the **firmware and battery level is unknown**.

I don't know whether my device has been added or not and I also don't know how to detect my gimbal beacon through my iOS app.

Any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed the Gimbal app? https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/gimbal-beacon-manager/id785688563?mt=8

Comment: Yes I have installed the gimbal app in my iPhone 4S it shows please turn on bluetooth to use the application even if the bluetooth is on.

Comment: Try turning the phone off and on again?  Your phone may have a faulty bluetooth chipset?  Are you sure it is a 4s and not a 4?  The Gimbal details won't show up on the developer site until you have successfully connected them via your phone

Comment: I have tried turning the phone off and on but no effect and other bluetooth devices detecting the phone. And my iPhone has iOS 7.1.1 and I am not sure whether it is iPhone 4 or 4s. Can you please tell me how to check that.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3939

Comment: Then it will not work. You need a 4S or later for BLE support

Comment: Ok I will get one and try again and then inform you

Comment: Ok now gimbal manager is working but how I can test if i am in the range of a gimbal. Can you help me with that. I will be very thankful. I am in a hurry and have to complete the gimbal integration by tomorrow. So any help will be grateful.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a member of the Gimbal developer program and they do not provide documentation without registering.  There are numerous examples of how to use core location with generic iBeacons

Comment: Ok...no issues...thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

If the beacons listed under your Gimbal Developer Account show unknown values for the firmware and battery levels that means your phone isn't communicating with the beacons. I suspect it has to do with the way the application being built has been configured with the Gimbal SDK or the sample app wasn't setup to work with your Gimbal Developer Account.

Once everything is configured correctly then when your phone comes in proximity of a Gimbal beacon it will capture everything about that beacon and then send it to Gimbal's backend service. The end result will be the correct status of the firmware and battery levels on your Gimbal Developer Account.

I suggest using the various Gimbal surveying tools available for download on their website to detect beacon signals, measuring effective ranges, etc. You will likely use them quite a bit to do proper surveying. Granted, you could always bake this functionality into your own app if desired.